# Проблема с отступами при переносе строки

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

У меня есть блок с текстом, ему назначен `padding`. При адаптации происходит перенос текста на другую строку, и край зарезается по самую букву. При этом line-height должен остаться между строками.

Для понимания прикладываю скрин:

[image]

Можно ли как-то сделать `padding` для каждого слова или как-то иначе реализовать данную задачу?

[image]

Comment: помоему нет. разделите фразы на составляющие и шаманьте медиа-запросами

Comment: А при адаптации не возникла идея уменьшить и размер текста?

Comment: @ZaArs, медиазапросы на подгонку спанов под текст - это какая-то жесть. Особенно если локализация понадобится.

Comment: @Air, а чем тебе перенос не угодил?

Comment: @Qwertiy, так это ни мне не угодил, а автору вопроса...

Answer (score 4):

Слова придётся обернуть в span'ы, но решение такое.
Обязательно чтобы ширина не становилась меньше самого длинного слова.

```css
div {
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 7em;
  outline: 1px dotted red;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  animation: width-change 10s linear infinite alternate;
}

.text {
  background: silver;
  box-shadow: 2em 0 0 silver;
}

.word {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

.spc {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 -1em;
}

@keyframes width-change {
  from { width: 7em; }
  to { width: 15em; }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class=text>
    <span class=word>Some</span><span class=spc></span>
    <span class=word>interesting</span><span class=spc></span>
    <span class=word>list</span><span class=spc></span>
    <span class=word>of</span><span class=spc></span>
    <span class=word>words</span><span class=spc></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Правда, есть некоторые косяки:

- Chrome 75, Edge 18 - всё идеально
- FF 67 - нет тени, серый фон кончается на 2em левее, чем надо
- IE 11 - размытие тени в 1px вместо 0, небольшой зазор между тенью и фоном, текст вылезает за пределы блока на 2em (последнее должно устраняться padding'ом)

Comment: ♦ прекрасный пример демонстрации своей идеи

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, я вот кроссбраузерность проверил - оказалось, не везде работает...

Answer (score 0):

Обернул каждое слово в спан, спану задал `margin-left:7px;` чтобы отступы между словами скрыть и потом медиками уменьшал размер текста, и все получилось нормально

Answer (score -2):

Оберните span в какой-нибуть контейнер, типа div, назначте bg диву и падинг тоже, уберите bg и padding в span.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: но нужен вот такой результат: http://prntscr.com/oan265

Comment: Хорошо, тогда заверните каждое отдельное слово в спан.

Comment: Удалите ответы и внесите правку в вопрос.

Comment: @СкрыльАлександр, просто так обернуть не получится - будут отступы у каждого слова, а он между словами не хочет.

Comment: @doox911, я сделал :)

Comment: обернул каждое слово в спан, спану задал margin-left:7px; - чтобы отступы между словами скрыть и потом медиками уменьшал азмер текста, и все получилось нормально